# escaping xml element name in java

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization

how do we escape xml element name in java

I am building xml with a run time data that have many special characters (e.g, "(") I know about StringEscapseUtils of apache-common-lang but it does not escape element name

any other option

Comment: Can you please give us an example?

Comment: Such escapers only exist for encodings where an official definition for escaping arbitrary data exists. These are only formats intended to contain arbitrary data. Element names are identifiers. They're not intended to be used for arbitrary data. This means there is not a generally accepted way to do it. However, there are ways to do it and it takes about 20 lines of code to do that. I wouldn't invest much time for searching if I think I need that. But I would invest some time think about a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am building xml with a run time data that have many special characters (e.g, "(") I know about StringEscapseUtils of apache-common-lang but it does not escape element name

I don't think such an escape mechanism has been formalized. `(` cannot be part of an element name. Here are the constraints for an [element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) name:

```
Name          ::= NameStartChar (NameChar)*
NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] |
                  [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D]
                  | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] |
                  [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] |
                  [#x203F-#x2040]
```